# Multiple alerts when pressing button on website with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Just starting to learn jQuery and running into a problems when fading. The alert appears 5 times every time I click the button to fade the circle and hide the words.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#circle").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
  });    
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So I guess there are five paragraphs then, as the callback fires for each of them

Comment: This will multiply for all the paragraphs!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple paragraphs, and the callback for the animation fires on each of them.

You can use a promise to solve it *(in later versions of jQ all animated methods returns a deferred)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide("slow").promise().done(function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/169m56c9/)